# How can I verify that a username is available in realtime in a MERN application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, validation

I am writing a registration form in React.js using TypeScript and each username that registers will have to register with a unique username. If I have a LoginForm component that takes in all the data from the form, how can I verify in real time that a username is not taken? I have a MongoDB dedicated cluster where every user document is stored, and each user has a username, which is a string, stored in the field "username". Basically, as a user is typing their username, I want to display a red alert that shows "Username is taken" while the username they've typed is taken, and "Username is unique" in green, when the username entered is unique.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.
The only idea I've come up with: Using the useEffect hook to capture the state of input every few seconds and make an axios call to the database, search for the username, and render an alert. However, I'm not sure if this is the best method because of the number of calls that will be made and possible latency.

Is there a best-practice way to do this? If there is, please point me in the right direction. Ideally, if you could outline a series of steps, i.e. 1. "Make an api call to x every time x happens", 2. ... then that would be helpful.

Comment: To check uniqueness of the username, you should query the api every time the user stops typing. How you implement the check for when the user stops typing is up to you, ideally you would implement this as when the user has not typed in 5 or so seconds.

Comment: You could trigger an API call from the onChange handler of the input every time the user stops typing for at least 200 - 300 ms (i suppose). A keyword to look for existing implementations might be "debouncing". Like "debouncing an API call on change event"